# : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, fixed, php-7.4

tried this code on two different WordPress sites. It was working on the first site. After I moved the template completely to my new site, I got this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

I do not know what is the reason, although it is the same template, plugins and everything

---

```
               
              <?php 
        
$novoteste = new ComicLatestChapters("6", "6");
$resultados = $novoteste->filter;
                foreach($resultados as $resultado => $novoteste) {
                                    $series_id =  $novoteste->post_id;
                                    $status = get_post_status($series_id);
                                    if($status !== 'publish' || $series_id == 20305){
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    $result = get_post($resultado);
                                    $sort_by    = $sort_setting['sortBy'];
                                    $sort_order = $sort_setting['sort'];
                                    $chapters = $wp_manga_functions->get_latest_chapters($series_id, null, 2, 0, $sort_by, $sort_order);
                                    $latest_chapter = $chapters[0];
                                    $semilatest_chapter = $chapters[1];
                                    $scheduled1 = $latest_chapter['schedule_time'];
                                    $scheduled2 = $semilatest_chapter['schedule_time'];
                                    $series_link = get_the_permalink($series_id);
                                    $chapter_slug1 = $latest_chapter['chapter_slug'];
                                    $chapter_slug2 = $semilatest_chapter['chapter_slug'];

                                    $type = $wp_manga_functions->get_manga_type( $manga_id );

                                    $chapter_name1 = $latest_chapter['chapter_name'];
                                    $chapter_name2 = $semilatest_chapter['chapter_name'];
                                    $mass_released = is_mass_released($series_id);
                                    $ch_1 = get_only_numbers($chapter_name1);
                                    $ch_2 = get_only_numbers($chapter_name2);   
                                    $rating = get_post_meta($series_id, '_manga_avarage_reviews', true);
                                    $chapter_index1 = $latest_chapter['chapter_index'];
                                    $chapter_index2 = $semilatest_chapter['chapter_index'];                                 
                                    $link1 = $wp_manga_functions->build_chapter_url($series_id, $chapter_slug1);
                                    $link2 = $wp_manga_functions->build_chapter_url($series_id, $chapter_slug2);
                                    $restored = get_post_meta($series_id, 'restored', true);
                                    $publish = $latest_chapter['date'];
                                    $publish2 = $semilatest_chapter['date'];
                                    $type = get_post_meta($series_id, '_wp_manga_chapter_type', true);
                                    $series_status = get_post_meta($series_id, '_wp_manga_status', true);
                                    if (isset($scheduled1)){
                                        $published = $wp_manga_functions->get_time_diff($scheduled1);}
                                        else{
                                            $published = $wp_manga_functions->get_time_diff($publish);
                                        }
                                    if (isset($scheduled2)){
                                        $published2 = $wp_manga_functions->get_time_diff($scheduled2);}
                                        else{
                                            $published2 = $wp_manga_functions->get_time_diff($publish2);
                                        }
                                    $series_class = get_post_meta($series_id, 'manga_custom_badges', true);
                                    $class_css = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($series_class));
                                    
                                    $novel1 =  get_post($series_id);
                                    $title =  $novel1->post_title;
                                    
                                    $description = $result->post_content;
                                    $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta($series_id, '_thumbnail_id', true);
                                    $thumbnail_link = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($series_id, array(290,395));
                                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the output `$resultados = $novoteste->filter;` Is it empty or not?
The code changes like this:

```
<?php 
$novoteste  = new ComicLatestChapters( "6", "6" );
$resultados = $novoteste->filter ?: array();
            
foreach( $resultados as $resultado => $novoteste ) {
........
}
```

Comment: The problem disappeared, but nothing appears

Comment: Because there is no data. Check your database. Or if you are using api, check it again